# Load a page from a AJAX-loaded div using vb (asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to achieve something that seems more complicated than I believe it really is.

I have multiple divs (in a comment field) in which I am loading a PostComment-page like this (of course inside `$(document).ready(function() {})`:

```
$('.form-feedback').each(function() {
    // load each textarea and then hide them. They should only be visible when a user clicks on the feedback-link.
    var commentid = $(this).data('id'); // Uhm... is this correct? Should I use attribute('id').val(); instead? I will check this out later...

    $('.form-feedback').load('PostFeedback.aspx?id=' + commentid);
    $('.form-feedback').hide();
});

<a href="#" class="show-hide-reply-feedback" id="<%#Eval("id")%>" title="Lämna en synpunkt">Lämna en synpunkt</a>
<div id="form-<%#Eval("id")%>" class="form-feedback">
    ... the form ...
</div>
```

This is my own interpretation of how to reuse the same textarea and submit button to post unique comments from - I believe there must be much better ways to do this, but for now I'm trying this one out. ;)

Anyway - my problem is that anytime I hit the submit button on PostFeedback.aspx the redirected page is loaded inside the div.form-feedback since that's where PostFeedback.aspx resides. The result is... well, let me put it like this: *silly*. :) Everything posts perfect - it just doesn't render as I want it to. The redirection in PostComment.aspx.vb looks like this:

```
Response.Redirect(Utilities.Helpers.ResolveUrl("~/Article.aspx?id=" & Request.QueryString("id"))
```

So, how do I load the redirected page outside that div, ie. as a new page in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what made the trick on this but suddenly things started to work. Things never *just happen* so there must be some reason for this to work, but anyway - this is the way I'm using my javascript if anyone else needs some inspiration out there. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-hide-reply-feedback').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr("href").css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).click(function () {
            var feedbackid = $(this).attr('id');

            $('form-feedback').empty(); // the purpose of this is to release any existing page-load from the div to remove all previous entered but unposted comments.
            $('#form-' + feebackid).load('PostFeedback.aspx?id=' + feedbackid, function(response, status, xhr) {
                var msg = 'Sorry but an error occured: ';

                $('#error').html(msg + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
});

<!-- The placeholder for the form fields -->
<a href="#" class="show-hide-reply-feedback" id="b91e45bf-4f3f-4480-a1c8-50d206ba0fb8">lämna en synpunkt</a>
<div id="form-b91e45bf-4f3f-4480-a1c8-50d206ba0fb8" rel="b91e45bf-4f3f-4480-a1c8-50d206ba0fb8" class="form-feedback"></div>
```